# How to link a google apps script in a google site

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm creating a google site for my company and I'm utilizing google apps scripts to do a little extra on the site. I would really like to link a script to a drop-down menu that I made. However, I can't figure out how to link the script. I know how to link a script just as a google gadget and as a stand alone link, but I would really like to have the script run when I click on an item from my drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Google don't let you put javascript in Google Sites.
They provide Apps Scripts instead, but as they work on an isolated world (on the server rather than the browser), its very tricky and has its ways.

Because its very different to standard page's javascript, you have to rethink your goal in terms of what Apps Scripts lets you do.

Google Apps Scripts lets you build an User Interface (using its yet experimental UI API) that can be visualized as a standalone script in a full page or inserted in a iframe in Sites.  This means you won't have a dropdown menu overlaping your site: you need an static space to visualize your script's UI.

There is another more primitive way to "embed" your scripts commands in your site: use links.  A link that fires a script, even with your own parameters, only to run de command, but without any UI.  You can make a menu with options, each of them fires a script.  But I'm not talking about dropdown menu.

**About Google Apps Scripts User Interfaces**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_gui_builder
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_ui

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "link the script", do you have code someplace else? By "link" it sounds like you mean to "Call" the code, with an event handler. I'll show you how to call a function with a ServerHandler triggered by either a GUI ListBox Change event or from a Button Click event.

In Google Apps Scrips (GAS) there are three methods to do GUI.

- [HTML Service](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) - Much like plain HTML, you could insert HTML form and input tags.
- [UI Service](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) - Much like java (as far as layout managers), see below.
- [GUI Builder](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder) - I suggest doing it manually first to better understand layout.

In Google Sites you can add most HTML directly without a script. The UI Service and GUI Builder will generate HTML form tags for you, and since there's rarely any reason to insert GUI elements unless you are executing some code you probably want to start with using these.

---

[Here is a Drop-Down list example](http://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/listbox)with some changes to show how a handler function can be called from multiple UI elements (which they call Widgets sometimes) and how to use the parameter:

```
function doGet(e) {         // use doGet() & UiApp to make a canvas.
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var doEvent = app.createServerHandler('doEvent').setId('doEvent');
    var myList = app.createListBox().setId('myList').setName('myList');
    myList.addItem('one');  // add items, I use single quote strings.
    myList.addItem('two').addItem('three')    // I know it looks weird.
    // Scripts let you do this, by returning self for your convenience.
        .addChangeHandler(                       
            app.createServerHandler('doEvent')
        );
    app.add(myList);                     // Add element to GUI.
    doEvent.addCallbackElement(myList);  // Add to Event Handler.

    app.add(app.createButton('Click Me').setId('myButton')
        .addClickHandler(doEvent));

    return app;
}   // Simple DropDown by Jason K.

function doEvent(e) { // use split() if isMultipleSelect is true
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.add(app.createLabel(
        'List Value is ' + e.parameter.myList
        + ' from ' + e.parameter.source));
    return app;
}
```

As far as troubleshooting, remember to add each element with app.add() and return app; at the end of doGet and each handler function.

Handlers execute a function like JavaScript onClick() or onChange() functions, most UI are not useful without handlers. ClientHandler are more efficient but ServerHandler do more, start with ServerHandlers and any simple functions can be converted to ClientHandlers for better performance. You can choose to space out your handlers or cram it all into one line-of-code, really a matter of personal preference however do assign it to a variable if you plan to use it for more than one GUI object. You may want to look up the different layout managers to make more fancy looking applications, or just use the GUI Builder. Also there use to be other create functions like app.createServerClickHandler() but I understand those were useless and are now deprecated so ignore any other references you find like that, however we do still use addChangeHandler() and addClickHandler() to the GUI elements themselves.

The setName() seems to be silly, it is only needed to set the parameter name (I hope they change that) so for now I suggest just setting it the same as the element id. I also made the Handler's variable name = its id = the event function name just to illustrate how they are all related.